Is there any specification on gRPC support guarantees as there is with protobuf?
For protobuf there are these 2 documents detailing for how long a version is supported (maintained) and what it the compatibility between code generated with some version when used with a runtime with some other version:

https://protobuf.dev/support/version-support/
https://protobuf.dev/support/cross-version-runtime-guarantee/

I can't find any similar document for gRPC, for how long a gRPC version is supposed to be maintained and for the code generated for gRPC, what is the level of compatibility when used with a different version at runtime.
It would also be good to know if there are any restrictions or guarantees when mixing up different protobuf and grpc versions.
I'm asking in particular for Python, but I guess this applies to any language.
I tried searching the internet and searching the https://grpc.io/, as well as the project repo https://github.com/grpc/grpc/. I was expecting to find some documents similar to the ones for protobuf, but I didn't find anything.
EDIT:
I wanted to phrase the question as generically as possible but I was referring to the Python code generation and runtime in particular, and more in particular using the grpc-tools package to generate the code (which I'm uncertain if it uses the regular protoc or something else, but I would guess it uses protoc).
This question from from the fact that I were generating the code with the latest version available but I was setting as the minimum supported version an older version. At some point protobuf (at least the Python gen code) started to add version information to the generated code and the runtime to check this version, and failing (or failing in indirect ways like an error importing ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime_version' from 'google.protobuf').
Then I observed the grpc stubs generated code also have some version info in the generated code and some runtime check, as I was getting errors like:

RuntimeError: The grpc package installed is at version 1.51.1, but the generated code in frequenz/api/microgrid/v1/microgrid_pb2_grpc.py depends on grpcio>=1.66.1. Please upgrade your grpc module to grpcio>=1.66.1 or downgrade your generated code using grpcio-tools<=1.51.1.

Since I found very detailed information on cross-version runtime guaratees for protobuf (and by this I mean protobuf.dev which seems to cover the runtime for multiple language), I was hoping to find the same for grpc (the grpc library, or grpcio Python package), so I can set the range of supported runtime versions in pyproject.toml accordingly.

I'm confused. For protobuf versioning you appear to be talking about the protoc code generator not the protobuf language versions.

When talking about gRPC versions though, I assume that you're talking about the libraries and packages that provide gRPC functionality in your project. These are completely separate concerns and may or may not be updated by the individual package maintainers at the same time.

I just updated the question to clarify a bit better what I mean by grpc version. Thanks!

gRPC's version support expectations can be found here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/versioning.md
And their release policy is here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/grpc_release_schedule.md

Thanks, this partially answers my question. It still doesn't talk about compatibility between the grpc stubs generated code and the runtime that actually runs them. Apparently the protoc plugin to do the generation is provided by grpcio-tools which lives in https://github.com/grpc/grpc too.

So, from the versioning.md and the error message I got, I'm assuming that grpc has also the restriction that generated code can only be run by the same or newer version of the runtime with the same major version, but I was hoping to get some official source stating this more explicitly, like it's done in the protobuf docs (cross-version runtime-guarantee).
